# Reverse the order of ListView display

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a SimpleCursorAdapter to retrieve information from a SQLite database and put it into a ListView. It's all textbook stuff:

```
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.viewexisting, c, from, to);
```

However, I would love for it to display the data in reverse. At the moment the oldest entry in the database appears at the top, and the newest appears at the bottom.

Comment: You can try ordering your sql statement. e.g. "Select .. from ... where ... order by date asc/desc"

Comment: Oh now I feel stupid! I'd completely forgotten that there was a method in my DBAdapter that performed a query! Thanks a lot, I'll add the solution in a second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of a list is dependent on how you structure your SQL Query. Specifically one that impacts this exactly is the Sort parameter inside of the SQLite query method. The last parameter is the column to sort by, depending on what this column is in your database it will sort it by that.. For example:

```
[database object].query(.., COL_NAME + " ASC");
```

**COL_NAME** is the name of the column and **ASC** stands for 'Ascending Order'

I believe its **DESC** for 'Decending Order'.

Remember that the column needs to be an integer, string, or a date. SQLite will use these attached with the Ascending Or Descending Parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. The provided answer isn't quite right as that changes the order in which records come out of the database. Imagine the original question author has 50 records in his database and he wants to pull out the 10 newest items from the database everytime, but let the user change the way those 10 items are displayed. He would not want to change his SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Or resort Hashmap in reversed order. Good alternative if you have fixed Database-results.