# Reverse order in ListView using SimpleCursorAdapter and SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, sql-order-by, simplecursoradapter

I am filling a ListView with data from my SQLite Database using a SimpleCursorAdapter. The data is fine but the latest entry is always inserted at the bottom of the ListView and I want to have it at the top.

I already found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860732/reverse-the-order-of-listview-display) but I don`t know how to import this to my project.
At the moment my SQL query looks like this:

```
public Cursor fetchAllProjects() {

  Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_ROUTERIP, KEY_PROJECTNAME, KEY_URL, KEY_CALIMERO}, 
    null, null, null, null, null);

  if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  return mCursor;
}
```

What do I have to change to see the ListView in descending order? Or do I have to change something at my SimpleCursorAdapter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the query, the 2nd to last parameter (null at the moment) is the `Order By` parameter: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

You'd need to pick the column by which you want to sort, and change that. To be safe, you should probably explicitly sort in both "normal" and "reverse" order, to be sure that it is ordering by the same column.

Comment: ok maybe I just dont get it, but which column should I pick if I want to reverse the order? I changed the query command to `Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_ROUTERIP, KEY_PROJECTNAME, KEY_URL, KEY_CALIMERO}, 
    null, null, null, KEY_PROJECTNAME+" DESC", null);` and now I receive a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Not sure why that wouldn't work. Here's an example that looks to be doing the same: http://www.anddev.org/post3998.html#p3998, but seems to have a different count of nulls. Maybe check the parameters and make sure that the 6th one is the Order By?

Comment: In your linked example they use the 7th one but I also tried this one and the result is again a NullPointerException....

Comment: Ah sorry the NullPointerException was from another line, this is the error from logcat `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HAVING clauses are only permitted when using a groupBy clause`

Comment: Solution:`Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ROUTERIP, KEY_PROJECTNAME, KEY_URL, KEY_CALIMERO}, null, null, null,  KEY_PROJECTNAME+" DESC");`

Answer (score 4):

To reverse the order I had to change the query in my SQL Handler like this!

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ROUTERIP, KEY_PROJECTNAME, KEY_URL, KEY_CALIMERO}, null, null, null,  KEY_PROJECTNAME+" DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use query, here's an alternative:

```
cursor.moveToLast();
do
{
    // your code
}
while (cursor.moveToPrevious());
```